# Docusign with CRM 365 Envelope Status Changes not working

Tags: c#, docusignapi, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9, docusignconnect

We are using Demo Environment of Docusign and creating Docusign Envelope with custom c# code including Document, Recipients, Tabs and Email Subject. In response, it is giving the EnvelopeId.

We are using this EnvelopeId in CRM 365 System Workflow which is having one step to execute Docusign Custom Workflow -> GetSignature. The workflow is succeed and auto creating one Docusign Transaction Record with Envelope Status as "sent".

Now we have completed the Docusign Review Process and got email of completion as well but the status changes doesn't reflect in CRM's Docusign Transaction Record.

"**Update Statuses**" Button is also not working and giving error as `Error with: Updated statuses. String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Docusign but looking at your error `String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s".` looks like something somewhere is failing. Could you check  [System logs](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2015/04/plug-in-trace-log-in-crm-2015-update-1/) and see which of the workflow/plugin is failing. It will give you more idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/) so they can assist you in troubleshooting this issue.